# How to Django reverse to pages created in Wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

I have a Wagtail model for an object.

```
    class ObjectPage(Page):
        # fields, not really important
```

I want to make the object editable by front-end users, so I have also created a generic update view to accomplish this. My question is how I can use Django's reverse() function to point to the edited object in my get_success_url() method:

```
    class EditObjectPage(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
        # model, template_name, and fields defined; not really important

        def get_success_url(self):
            return("ObjectPage", kwargs={"slug" : self.object.slug})   # doesn't work
            return("object_page_slug", kwargs={"slug" : self.object.slug})   # also doesn't work
```

I know how to do this when I'm explicitly defining the URL name in my urls.py file, but in this case, the URL is created as a Wagtail page and is handled by this line of my urls.py:

```
url(r"", include(wagtail_urls)),
```

I've been searching the documentation for whether Wagtail pages are assigned names that can be reversed to, but I'm finding nothing in the official documentation or here on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page object provides a [`get_url` method](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/pages/model_reference.html#wagtail.core.models.Page.get_url) - `get_success_url` should be able to accept this directly, so there's no need to use `reverse`.

```
def get_success_url(self):
    return self.object.get_url()
```

Internally the URL route used by `get_url` is `wagtail_serve`, so if you absolutely need to go through `reverse`, you could [replicate the logic there](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/27432e6c3ffc18c0243d1a6bb1fa83c71dd7cb6f/wagtail/core/models.py#L1542-L1543).

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It's so often the simplest bits of code that are hardest to track down in the documentation.